# Wordpress W3 Cache is over cacheing -- and dont know how to approach the problem

Tags: wordpress, caching, w3c

I created an LMS, where teachers approve students to view certain lessons, using the Educator plugin which is no longer available. I had never installed a Cache plugin cause I know nothing of it, but time performance led me to W3 and a tutorial on recommended.

Now, I am getting people unable to see their course work even when logged in. Meaning, they cannot access a blog post that is blocked by default to all users but them. I have the option of "dont cache for logged in users" checked.

Here's where I am at a loss: People in the same course can see the post... and i can always see it myself. Sometimes the person reloads and it works. And since I am just a 3rd party, I don't have names/emails of people with the issue. So I have no idea what they see, how they see it, and how to debug.

So, after this block of text, here's my hypothesis and what I need help with:
Hypothesis: Everything is blocked by default, thus a person who is re-entering after W3 was installed needs to basically wait for his browser-server to agree on what he can see again.

If this is wrong cause I know nothing of cacheing... how do I approach this? re-install and start adding cache options one by one, waiting a few days to see if any student has issues?

Sorry if this is not too technical a question, I just need that first clue to get started :)

Comment: We don't really have enough information here to help (and I'm also not sure this is a programming-related question). But one thing to note is that it *could* be to do with the plugin, but it also could be something else. Caching can happen in numerous places - not just this plugin but also other plugins, sessions, the visitor's browser or even the hosting server .

Comment: Yea, I know it's not information, that's just all the information I have :( That's why I am not even sure where to start. Atm, my plan is to wait a bit more and see if I keep hearing issues. The other is to just say it's speed vs this problem, which would mean I just unistall and stay with the slow website.

How can I check if it's other stuff? Is there a place to start my search that you can think of?

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the .htaccess file. most likely cache code has been added to this file. that's why you have problems with the cache.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. That's a very specific assumption based on the little information we've been given! If you believe this is the solution, then please edit your question to explain why this is happening and how to fix the problem in `.htaccess`, so that your answer it is useful both to the OP and other users with similar issues.